# How to implement tree traversal with tail recusrion

Tags: scala

I wrote simple traversal function:

```
case class Node(data: String, childs: Seq[Node] = Seq.empty)

def travers(root: Node, visit: String => Unit): Unit = {

  def recur(n: Node): Unit = {
    visit(n.data)
    for (c <- n.childs) recur(c)
  }

  recur(root)
}

val root = Node("1",
           Seq(Node("2",
               Seq(Node("3"), Node("4")))))

travers(root, s => println(s))
```

How to implement it with tail recursion?

Comment: Is order important to you? You have two good answers now, one which is breadth-first, one which is depth-first (like the implementation in the question) :)

Comment: Good point @JoeK - got my upvote :)

Comment: Important, for educational purposes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try changing the recursion to handle a *sequence* of children at each iteration - and get a *breadth-first* traversal (unlike the depth-first order @JoeK's answer and your implementation share):

```
def travers(root: Node, visit: String => Unit): Unit = {
  @tailrec
  def recur(ns: List[Node]): Unit = {
    ns.foreach(n => visit(n.data))
    ns.flatMap(_.childs) match {
      case Nil => // done
      case more => recur(more)
    }
  }
  recur(List(root))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this by "manually" managing a stack of nodes to visit, like this:

```
def travers(root: Node, visit: String => Unit): Unit = {

  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def recur(stack: List[Node]): Unit = stack match {
    case Node(d, children) :: rest => {
      visit(d)
      recur(children.toList ++ rest)
    }
    case Nil => {}
  }

  recur(List(root))
}
```